# Monitoring Windows Machine/Server

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-server-2012, quickbooks

We currently have a business running QuickBooks who complain of sluggishness. A quick view of TaskMan does not show CPU maxed or network port flooded.

The server is 2012 and is a Windows 7 guest running in Hyper-V.

Is there a way like SAR for Linux to monitor to maybe see what could be causing problems or a way to debug this issue?

The guest VM has full access to 2 cores, 8GBs of RAM. Nothing is really running on the machine but QBs such as the files/DB which are accessed over the network.

Comment: Your running the client software within a windows 7 virtual machine?

Comment: How many vCPUs do you have allocated to the VM?   How much RAM?   What type of storage are you using to store your data on?   While it might be expensive, there are huge positives in terms of responsiveness if you are using an SSD (240GB suggested) to store the VHD for the Windows 7 VM.

Comment: 2 vCPUS at 2GHz. It's nothing but hosting the QB Files/DB. 8GB of RAM for the guest but the employees still report sluggishness which I can't example.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx) (perfmon) is the tool you're looking for.  There are tons of performance counters you can monitor and graph and alerts you can set.